# Ant scriptdef - javascript referencing external libs

Tags: javascript, ant

Is there a way to use external libraries like jQuery in ant scriptdef task? I want to use framework inside it.

Comment: jQuery is primarily for DOM manipulation, and there's no DOM in the JavaScript environment for ant script tasks.

Comment: That is correct, but I can extend rhino or include other / own DOMParser functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The framework may not work in the way you want within Ant, but you can use the Ant FileUtils class to import JavasSript, something like this within your `<script>` task:

```
eval( '' + org.apache.tools.ant.util.FileUtils.readFully(
                   new java.io.FileReader( 'yourscript.js' ) ) );
```

Unfortunately, I don't think the Rhino `load()` method works from within Ant, so the above looks like the simplest solution.